# Stop Page Refresh on fancybox close

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox

I'm making a new (self-hosted) wordpress.org website for a friend of mine.  The theme (Lensa by colorlabs) came bundled with fancybox V1.34. (I'm more familiar with V2)

I've got some basic script to load images from the posts in the fancybox, however when I close the fancybox the page reloads (which I don't want).

I've added :

`onClosed : function(){ parent.location.reload(false);},`

But this has no effect.

Can anyone help find which it is, and/or how I can stop this behaviour?

I guess it could be coming from any one of the built in scripts of the theme (But I can't spot it, possibly "Masonry" script in plugins.js but every time I edit it I screw it up!).

Example:
http://talesfromthesaddle.com/shortwaywp/2010/01/06/chapter-20-the-early-retirement-of-lady-p/

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: parent.location.reload(false) will reload the page from cache,  parent.location.reload(true) will reload the page from server. It will reload in both cases so it is not what you want

Comment: Mmm, okay, I'll take that back out, thanks for the info.